# Running Android Tests in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, intellij-idea

When I created the project, a "test" directory was created with it, along with an example unit test class. I want to be able to run this test (and then create my own tests and run them) but I am not able to (there is no option to run it when I click "Run..."). The example unit test class has a "red" icon, further indicating it isn't being recognized as a runnable file. What do I have to do to run it?

[image]

EDIT:

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.package"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: post here your build.gradle file

Comment: you are working in IntelliJ? Just right click on the src folder in the test folder and pick Mark directory as ----> Test Source Root

Comment: I am not sure if that is the exactly same wording as in IntelliJ, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ do you run?

Comment: @XaverKapeller That worked, thank you!